# How do I use integer number literals when using generic types?

Tags: generics, int, rust, traits

I wanted to implement a function computing the number of digits within any generic type of integer. Here is the code I came up with:

```
extern crate num;
use num::Integer;

fn int_length<T: Integer>(mut x: T) -> u8 {
    if x == 0 {
        return 1;
    }

    let mut length = 0u8;
    if x < 0 {
        length += 1;
        x = -x;
    }

    while x > 0 {
        x /= 10;
        length += 1;
    }

    length
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", int_length(45));
    println!("{}", int_length(-45));
}
```

And here is the compiler output

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:5:13
  |
5 |     if x == 0 {
  |             ^ expected type parameter, found integral variable
  |
  = note: expected type `T`
             found type `{integer}`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:10:12
   |
10 |     if x < 0 {
   |            ^ expected type parameter, found integral variable
   |
   = note: expected type `T`
              found type `{integer}`

error: cannot apply unary operator `-` to type `T`
  --> src/main.rs:12:13
   |
12 |         x = -x;
   |             ^^

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:15:15
   |
15 |     while x > 0 {
   |               ^ expected type parameter, found integral variable
   |
   = note: expected type `T`
              found type `{integer}`

error[E0368]: binary assignment operation `/=` cannot be applied to type `T`
  --> src/main.rs:16:9
   |
16 |         x /= 10;
   |         ^ cannot use `/=` on type `T`
```

I understand that the problem comes from my use of constants within the function, but I don't understand why the trait specification as `Integer` doesn't solve this.

[The documentation for `Integer`](https://docs.rs/num/0.1.37/num/trait.Integer.html) says it implements the `PartialOrd`, etc. traits with `Self` (which I assume refers to `Integer`). By using integer constants which also implement the `Integer` trait, aren't the operations defined, and shouldn't the compiler compile without errors?

I tried suffixing my constants with `i32`, but the error message is the same, replacing `_` with `i32`.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Many things are going wrong here:

1. [As Shepmaster says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28565674/155423), `0` and `1` cannot be converted to everything implementing `Integer`. Use `Zero::zero` and `One::one` instead.
2. `10` can definitely not be converted to anything implementing `Integer`, you need to use `NumCast` for that
3. `a /= b` is not sugar for `a = a / b` but an separate trait that `Integer` does not require.
4. `-x` is an unary operation which is not part of `Integer` but requires the `Neg` trait (since it only makes sense for signed types).

Here's an implementation. Note that you need a bound on `Neg`, to make sure that it results in the same type as `T`

```
extern crate num;

use num::{Integer, NumCast};
use std::ops::Neg;

fn int_length<T>(mut x: T) -> u8
where
    T: Integer + Neg<Output = T> + NumCast,
{
    if x == T::zero() {
        return 1;
    }

    let mut length = 0;
    if x < T::zero() {
        length += 1;
        x = -x;
    }

    while x > T::zero() {
        x = x / NumCast::from(10).unwrap();
        length += 1;
    }

    length
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", int_length(45));
    println!("{}", int_length(-45));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for pointing all that out ! I guess I'm better off replacing `Int + Neg <...>` by `SignedInt` !

Comment: And thus any number if changing a bit your function \o/ Thanks a lot !

Comment: SignedInt has one problem, you won't be able to use unsigned values ;) see playpen: http://is.gd/YPhjla

Comment: @ker I thought that unsigned int didn't implemented the `Neg` traits... But I obviously didn't took a sufficient look at it ! Thanks ! I definitely  have some reading waiting for me...

Comment: @Shepmaster's example [updated for 1.1 here](http://is.gd/m86OnY). Sadly, I'm not savvy enough to detect the "wow" optimization ker mentions.

Comment: just add `#[inline(never)]` to your `ten` function, turn on release mode and generate the llvm code. Then you can see, that the monomorphised generic function for `i32` is optimized to a single `ret i32 10` statement

Answer (score 8):

The problem is that the `Integer` trait can be implemented by *anything*. For example, you could choose to implement it on your own struct! There wouldn't be a way to convert the literal `0` or `1` to your struct. I'm too lazy to show an example of implementing it, because there's 10 or so methods. ^_^

## `num::Zero` and `num::One`

This is why [`Zero::zero`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/trait.Zero.html) and [`One::one`](https://docs.rs/num/0.4.0/num/trait.One.html) exist. You can (very annoyingly) create all the other constants from repeated calls to those.

```rust
use num::{One, Zero}; // 0.4.0

fn three<T>() -> T
where
    T: Zero + One,
{
    let mut three = Zero::zero();
    for _ in 0..3 {
        three = three + One::one();
    }
    three
}
```

## `From` and `Into`

You can also use the `From` and `Into` traits to convert to your generic type:

```rust
use num::Integer; // 0.4.0
use std::ops::{DivAssign, Neg};

fn int_length<T>(mut x: T) -> u8
where
    T: Integer + Neg<Output = T> + DivAssign,
    u8: Into<T>,
{
    let zero = 0.into();
    if x == zero {
        return 1;
    }

    let mut length = 0u8;
    if x < zero {
        length += 1;
        x = -x;
    }

    while x > zero {
        x /= 10.into();
        length += 1;
    }

    length
}

fn main() {
    println!("{}", int_length(45));
    println!("{}", int_length(-45));
}
```

See also:

- [How do I use floating point number literals when using generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50767912/155423)

Comment: Why `u8: Into<T>` instead of `T: From<u8>`?