# How do I use floating point number literals when using generic types?

Tags: floating-point, rust, traits, literals

Regular float literals do not work:

```
extern crate num_traits;

use num_traits::float::Float;

fn scale_float<T: Float>(x: T) -> T {
    x * 0.54
}

fn main() {
    let a: f64 = scale_float(1.23);
}
```

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
 --> src/main.rs:6:9
  |
6 |     x * 0.54
  |         ^^^^ expected type parameter, found floating-point variable
  |
  = note: expected type `T`
             found type `{float}`
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use the [`FromPrimitive` trait](https://docs.rs/num-traits/0.2.4/num_traits/cast/trait.FromPrimitive.html):

```
use num_traits::{cast::FromPrimitive, float::Float};

fn scale_float<T: Float + FromPrimitive>(x: T) -> T {
    x * T::from_f64(0.54).unwrap()
}
```

Or the standard library `From` / `Into` traits

```
fn scale_float<T>(x: T) -> T
where
    T: Float,
    f64: Into<T>
{
    x * 0.54.into()
}
```

See also:

- [How do I use number literals with the Integer trait from the num crate?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28565440/155423)

Comment: Thanks.  First one works, second one doesn't due to lack of f64->f32 conversion.  Fixed on [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=35c7f1b82aac65be5119001fc586e181&version=stable&mode=debug).  Inspection of assembly shows this is zero cost so I'm happy!

Comment: @goertzenator you could go the other way (`f32: Into<T>`).

Answer (score 3):

In certain cases, you can add a restriction that the generic type must be able to be multiplied by the type of the literal. Here, we allow any type that can be multiplied by a `f64` so long as it produces the output type of `T` via the trait bound `Mul<f64, Output = T>`:

```
use num_traits::float::Float; // 0.2.6
use std::ops::Mul;

fn scale_float<T>(x: T) -> T
where
    T: Float + Mul<f64, Output = T>,
{
    x * 0.54
}

fn main() {
    let a: f64 = scale_float(1.23);
}
```

This may not work directly for the original problem, but it might depending on what concrete types you need to work with.

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a `Float` from a literal directly. I suggest an approach similar to the `FloatConst` trait:

```
trait SomeDomainSpecificScaleFactor {
    fn factor() -> Self;
}

impl SomeDomainSpecificScaleFactor for f32 {
    fn factor() -> Self {
        0.54
    }
}

impl SomeDomainSpecificScaleFactor for f64 {
    fn factor() -> Self {
        0.54
    }
}

fn scale_float<T: Float + SomeDomainSpecificScaleFactor>(x: T) -> T {
    x * T::factor()
}
```

([link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=ed1f0b6f24295827e86786671bc54508&version=stable&mode=debug))

Answer (score 1):

These days the `numeric_literals` [crate](https://docs.rs/numeric_literals/latest/numeric_literals/) and its `replace_float_literals` feature can be helpful in doing the necessary substitutions on a complex piece of code.