# How to preserve the accuracy of a floating point literal in Rust when using generics?

Tags: rust, floating-point, precision

What's a reasonable strategy for preserving the accuracy of a floating point literal in Rust when using generics?  As an example, consider the following code:

```rust
// External functions
use std::fmt::LowerExp;

// Some random struct parameterized on a float type
struct Foo<Float> {
    x: Float,
    y: Float,
}

// Some random, generic function
fn bar<Float>(x: Float)
where
    Float: LowerExp + From<f32>,
{
    let foo = Foo::<Float> { x, y: 0.45.into() };
    println!("x = {:.16e} y = {:.16e}", foo.x, foo.y);
}

fn main() {
    bar::<f32>(0.45);
    bar::<f64>(0.45);
}
```

Here, we get the output:

```
x = 4.4999998807907104e-1 y = 4.4999998807907104e-1
x = 4.5000000000000001e-1 y = 4.4999998807907104e-1
```

This makes sense.  The first `0.45` was parsed knowing whether or not we were an `f32` or an `f64`.  However, the second was parsed as an `f32` in both cases because of the trait `From<f32>`.  Now, I'd like the output to be

```
x = 4.4999998807907104e-1 y = 4.4999998807907104e-1
x = 4.5000000000000001e-1 y = 4.5000000000000001e-1
```

where `y` is parsed and set using the precision of the generic `Float`.  One attempt to do that is by adding an additional trait of `From<f64>`.  However, this is not satisfied by `f32`, so we get a compiler error.  If we remove that use case and run the code:

```rust
// External functions
use std::fmt::LowerExp;

// Some random struct parameterized on a float type
struct Foo<Float> {
    x: Float,
    y: Float,
}

// Some random, generic function
fn bar<Float>(x: Float)
where
    //Float: LowerExp + From<f32>,
    Float: LowerExp + From<f32> + From<f64>,
{
    let foo = Foo::<Float> { x, y: 0.45.into() };
    println!("x = {:.16e} y = {:.16e}", foo.x, foo.y);
}

fn main() {
    //bar::<f32> (0.45);
    bar::<f64>(0.45);
}
```

we get what we want:

```
x = 4.5000000000000001e-1 y = 4.5000000000000001e-1
```

at the expense of no longer working for `f32`.  Alternatively, it's been suggested that we can use the `num` crate.  Unfortunately, unless I'm missing something, this appears to run into an issue with [double rounding](https://www.exploringbinary.com/double-rounding-errors-in-floating-point-conversions/).  The program:

```rust
// External functions
use num::FromPrimitive;
use std::fmt::LowerExp;

// Some random struct parameterized on a float type
struct Foo<Float> {
    x: Float,
    y: Float,
}

// Some random, generic function
fn bar<Float>(x: Float)
where
    Float: LowerExp + FromPrimitive,
{
    let foo = Foo::<Float> {
        x,
        y: <Float as FromPrimitive>::from_f64(
            0.5000000894069671353303618843710864894092082977294921875,
        )
        .unwrap(),
    };
    println!("x = {:.16e} y = {:.16e}", foo.x, foo.y);
}

fn main() {
    bar::<f32>(0.5000000894069671353303618843710864894092082977294921875f32);
    bar::<f64>(0.5000000894069671353303618843710864894092082977294921875f64);
}
```

Produces

```
x = 5.0000005960464478e-1 y = 5.0000011920928955e-1
x = 5.0000008940696716e-1 y = 5.0000008940696716e-1
```

This is problematic because `x` and `y` differ in the `f32` case.

Anyway, is there a reasonable strategy for insuring the floating point literal is converted the same in both cases?

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [How do I use floating point number literals when using generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50767912/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: @Shepmaster Unless I'm missing something, I think the num crate doesn't deal with issues caused by double rounding.  I updated the questions with some code that demonstrates this.