# How do I phrase a function's type constraint to permit the addition of values of different types?

Tags: generics, rust, operator-overloading, type-constraints

I intend to overload some operators, but am working my way up to it because the syntax is baffling. As an intermediate step, I am trying to write a function that adds two values that already support addition. My function will take as arguments values of types &A and B, call a function to turn B into a C, then clone the A so I can perform A + C to get another A and return it. To make it simple for this question, B is `i64` and C is `Duration` from the `chrono` crate.

**The part that confuses me is the type bounds.** How do I say that you can add A + Duration to get another A (and get the lifetimes straight)? A is not `Copy`, but I am happy cloning it. Example types of A are `Date` and `Datetime`, which both implement the `Datelike` trait.

```
use std::ops;
use chrono::Duration;
use chrono::{Date, Datelike, offset::TimeZone};

fn add_datelike_and_duration<A>(a: &A, days: i64) -> A 
where A: Datelike + Clone,
... something I can't figure out ... 
{
   let duration = Duration::days(days);
   let new_a = a.clone() + duration;
   let modified_new_a: A = ... do more stuff ...
   modified new_a
}
```

What did not work was this:

```
for<'a> 'a + A: ops::Add<Output = A>
```

(Note: The function is a little more complex. I am turning a new kind of duration that is a number of years and months into an approximate number of days, adding them to the date, then moving forward or backward a few days to match the day of the month, unless the starting day is the 31st and we end up in a 30-day month, or end up in February. Months and years vary in how long they are, making this tricky. This is part of XPATH YearMonth duration support.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To say that `A` can be added to a `Duration` to yield another `A`:

```
A: ops::Add<Duration, Output = A>
//          ^^^^^^^^ add this part
```

The `Add` trait (along with most of the traits in `std::ops`) has a type parameter that defaults to `Self`, so when you write `A: Add` it means `A: Add<A>` and `A: Add<Output = A>` means `Add<A, Output = A>`. To add `A` to `Duration` you have to explicitly override this default.

Adding a lifetime (`'a`) is only necessary if you want to add references.

### See also

- [How do I require a generic type implement an operation like Add, Sub, Mul, or Div in a generic function?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29184358/3650362)
- [How to write a trait bound for adding two references of a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34630695/3650362)
- [How do I use integer number literals when using generic types?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28565440/3650362)

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks. All the examples I had seen were for adding two of the same type.